# Google Cloud Functions minInstances Pricing

Tags: firebase, function, cloud, instance, minimum

Is there any pricing information regarding deploying cloud functions with minInstances greater than 0? Also, when I deployed the function with runWith({ minInstances: 1}), the edit function page at console.cloud.google.com does not reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

You can find pricing info [on the Firebase Pricing Page](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing). Note this info to figure out the cost of minimum instances

> kept idle refers to idle billable time of instances kept warm using minimum instances.

You can also get a quote when you deploy:

1. Change your function to use `minInstances`

```
export const example = functions.https.onCall( ...
export const example = functions.runWith({minInstances: 1}).https.onCall( ...
```

2. Deploy via `firebase deploy --only functions`
3. The command line should prompt you with a quote and confirmation input such as:

> functions: The following functions have reserved minimum instances. This will reduce the frequency of cold starts but increases the minimum cost. You will be charged for the memory allocation and a fraction of the CPU allocation of instances while they are idle.

> With these options, your minimum bill will be $153.75 in a 30-day month

> ? Would you like to proceed with deployment? (y/N)

Also a tip: I use cloud scheduler to keep my functions warm as it's a small fraction of the cost and works just as well for my use case.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to use cloud scheduler to keep functions warm? Sounds like something I'd like to try